# Entity Framework 5 Code First, WebApi and how to create POST method with ModelState.IsValid and identity column

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5

I'm working on a project which uses Entity Framework 5 Code First, WebApi and ASPNET MVC 4.
I've a model like this one

```
public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this configuration

```
public class CategoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Categoria>
{
    public CategoryMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Id)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        this.Property(t => t.Name)
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        this.Property(t => t.Description)
            .HasMaxLength(100);
    }
}
```

Now, in my webapi controller (in the POST method) I'm trying to validate the model sent, but as it is a POST (create) and the Id is IDENTITY, it's coming null or empty, thus the Model.Valid says it is not Valid.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Category category)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ...
        return response;
    }

    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Is there any solution besides changing the type of column and besides not checking if the model is valid?

Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't personally worked with the WebAPI, but is there some problem working with view models in the WebAPI instead of the actual domain object?

Create a "CreateCategory" view model class and bind that to the POST verb. This view model would be the same as your domain class less the fact it wouldn't expose an ID property and whatever other changes you'd like. Since there's no property to validate, there's nothing to trip up validation on.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(CreateCategoryViewModel category)
```

You validate the view model with Model.IsValid, it passes validation, then you map the view model to your actual model object.

Should work much the same as a standard MVC action binding a view model.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I know I'll need to use ViewModel at some time, but Id needs tobe exposed, otherwise the Id on the View will not be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface (say ICategory) that duplicates the Category properties, Name and Description, and have the Category class implement that interface.  Then modify your HTTPRespoonseMessge Post method to take take a parameter of type ICategory.

public HttpResponseMessage Post (ICategory category)
{
}

Comment: So, you mean the same as ViewModel only having the interface between the ViewModel and the Entity right?
Why is that a better approach than ViewModel?

Comment: I believe the advantage is that when you make the test using the ModelState.IsValid, if the object being test implements the interface I suggested, then it will not have the ID field be part of the validation test (which is what is making the validation fail in the code you posted) and therefore the validation will pass.